# Zeroing a file from command-line

Tags: windows, command-line, secure-erase, wipe

Is there a built-in command in Windows 7 or higher to **fill a file with zero / NULL bytes**?

The processing should happen **in-place** (i.e. it should modify the actual disk sectors / bytes of the file), and not create a new file.

Something like:

```
zero c:\temp\*.*
```

or

```
zero hello.bin
```

that would do this:

```
Before: hello.bin (500 MB)
5D 1A CB FF FF C0 ... AA CD 0F FF


After: hello.bin (500 MB)
00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 00 00 00 00
```

---

If there's nothing built-in for this, what other solutions exist? Or would I have to do it in C?

Comment: Can you shed some light on why you want 500 MB of `00 00`, vs. `FF FF` or securely deleting the file?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator When using a secure delete tool, we cannot check that it has been zeroed before deleting with wxHexEditor because the fîle doesn't exist anymore (or we would need to remember the sector on disk and open whole disk with wxHexEditor). If the fîle is just zeroed and not deleted, we can open and view it and check.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is truly secure. For example, this method doesn't sound like it will securely delete any of the file's data that's stored in the MFT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a built-in command in Windows to fill a file with zero / NULL bytes?

Yes. You can use `fsutil` for this:

```
> fsutil file setzerodata /?
Usage : fsutil file setzerodata offset=<val> length=<val> <filename>
   offset : File offset, the start of the range to set to zeroes
   length : Byte length of the zeroed range
   Eg : fsutil file setzerodata offset=100 length=150 C:\Temp\sample.txt
```

To zero fill a complete file you will need to use an offset of `0` and you will need to know the file length.

---

#### Can we use batch file that would compute the size automatically?

Of course.

Use the following batch file (zero.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%1) do (
  fsutil file setzerodata offset=0 length=%%~za %%a
)
endlocal
```

Usage:

- You can pass a single filename as an argument: `zero test.txt` or a wildcard: `zero *.txt`

Example:

```
> type test.txt
abc
foo$
foo
bar

> zero test.txt
Zero data is changed

> type test.txt

>
```

[image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [fsutil](http://ss64.com/nt/fsutil.html) - File and Volume specific commands, Hardlink management, Quota management, USN, Sparse file, Object ID and Reparse point management
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: Thanks. Can we do a batch that would work like this `zero myfile.bin` ie that would compute the size automatically?

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, with the batch it's wonderful, since it accepts wildcards `*.txt`! A small thing (not a big deal if not possible easily, just asking in case it's possible with just one or two more lines in the batch): would it work also recursively for all files in subfolders? Like `zero -r c:\temp\ ` would zero all files in this folder or in its subfolders.

Comment: ... And a last one: is `fsutil setzerodata` really 100% safe? i.e. isn't there a risk that it *allocates new sectors* on disk to write the zero bytes, and leave the previous data still somewhere on disk? ;) Is it documented that it replaces by zero bytes **in-place**?

Comment: @Basj I've no idea whether it is totally safe :)

Comment: @Basj `zero -r c:\temp` could be done, but would require a more complicated batch file (parsing parameters etc). It's not something I would want to spend the time on to get it right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavidPostill. It's already perfect as it is now (I just asked this in case subdir recursive could have been added with just a few more characters in the batch, like adding a flag `-r` in the `for` loop, but as it's not possible, no need to spend more time on this, it's good already!)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a solution, but if you have [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you just do (example for a 500000000 bytes file) :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=MyFile.zero bs=1 count=500000000
```

This is the same method you would use at **any Unix-like** operating system.